# Jump to PIC32MZ FreeRTOS application using bootloader

Tags: bootloader, freertos, pic32, mplab-5.45

I have made a custom board with a PIC32MZ2048EMF100 and a LAN8720, ATWINC1500 ....

I wrote a program that works very well on this board and uses FreeRTOS (because of ATWINC1500), now I'm trying to do OTA using bootloader (I need the swapping between banks). (MPLAB + Harmony 3)

when I use bootloader as loadable project with the application (using hexmate to merge the two hex), I setted a led after SYS_Initialize(), the led blinks (I can run the app using the bootloader) but the app crashes in the SYS_Tasks() ( in prvCheckTasksWaitingTermination() function)

I need some modifications in linker scripts ?? is something specific to the FreeRTOS ??

Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to get this working?